# mingw ld cannot find some library which is exist in the search path

Tags: c, gcc, mingw, ld

I'm using vim+mingw, somehow, the terminal is still the window command.
so i google it, and using mintty. but when run vim, it hang forever until i type C-c.
i find [this page](https://code.google.com/p/mintty/issues/detail?id=56)
,and wana try winpty.
but when i compile it , it comes out:

```
$ make
Linking ../build/console.exe
c:\mingw32\bin\ld.exe: cannot find -lpthread
c:\mingw32\bin\ld.exe: cannot find -luser32
c:\mingw32\bin\ld.exe: cannot find -lkernel32
c:\mingw32\bin\ld.exe: cannot find -ladvapi32
c:\mingw32\bin\ld.exe: cannot find -lshell32
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status
make: *** [../build/console.exe] Error 1
```

then i try `gcc -lpthread --verbose`, it is able to find pthread.a.
then i try`ld -lpthread --verbose`,the output is

```
==================================================
attempt to open /mingw/mingw32/lib/libpthread.dll.a failed
attempt to open /mingw/mingw32/lib/pthread.dll.a failed
attempt to open /mingw/mingw32/lib/libpthread.a failed
attempt to open /mingw/mingw32/lib/pthread.lib failed
attempt to open /mingw/mingw32/lib/libpthread.dll failed
attempt to open /mingw/mingw32/lib/pthread.dll failed
attempt to open /mingw/mingw32/lib\libpthread.a failed
attempt to open /mingw/lib/libpthread.dll.a failed
attempt to open /mingw/lib/pthread.dll.a failed
attempt to open /mingw/lib/libpthread.a failed
attempt to open /mingw/lib/pthread.lib failed
attempt to open /mingw/lib/libpthread.dll failed
attempt to open /mingw/lib/pthread.dll failed
attempt to open /mingw/lib\libpthread.a failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/libpthread.dll.a failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/pthread.dll.a failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/libpthread.a failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/pthread.lib failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/libpthread.dll failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/pthread.dll failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib\libpthread.a failed
attempt to open /lib/libpthread.dll.a failed
attempt to open /lib/pthread.dll.a failed
attempt to open /lib/libpthread.a failed
attempt to open /lib/pthread.lib failed
attempt to open /lib/libpthread.dll failed
attempt to open /lib/pthread.dll failed
attempt to open /lib\libpthread.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/libpthread.dll.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/pthread.dll.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/libpthread.a failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/pthread.lib failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/libpthread.dll failed
attempt to open /usr/lib/pthread.dll failed
attempt to open /usr/lib\libpthread.a failed
attempt to open /mingw/mingw32/lib/libpthread.dll.a failed
attempt to open /mingw/mingw32/lib/pthread.dll.a failed
attempt to open /mingw/mingw32/lib/libpthread.a failed
attempt to open /mingw/mingw32/lib/pthread.lib failed
attempt to open /mingw/mingw32/lib/libpthread.dll failed
attempt to open /mingw/mingw32/lib/pthread.dll failed
attempt to open /mingw/mingw32/lib\pthread.lib failed
attempt to open /mingw/lib/libpthread.dll.a failed
attempt to open /mingw/lib/pthread.dll.a failed
attempt to open /mingw/lib/libpthread.a failed
attempt to open /mingw/lib/pthread.lib failed
attempt to open /mingw/lib/libpthread.dll failed
attempt to open /mingw/lib/pthread.dll failed
attempt to open /mingw/lib\pthread.lib failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/libpthread.dll.a failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/pthread.dll.a failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/libpthread.a failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/pthread.lib failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/libpthread.dll failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib/pthread.dll failed
attempt to open /usr/local/lib\pthread.lib failed
attempt to open /lib/libpthread.dll.a failed
attempt to open /lib/pthread.dll.a failed
attempt to open /lib/libpthread.a failed
attempt to open /lib/pthread.lib failed
attempt to open /lib/libpthread.dll failed
attempt to open /lib/pthread.dll failed
```

then i try `find /mingw -name *pthread*`the output is

```
$ find /mingw -name *pthread*
/mingw/bin/pthreadGC2.dll
/mingw/bin/pthreadGCE2.dll
/mingw/include/pthread.h
/mingw/lib/libpthread.a
/mingw/lib/libpthread.dll.a
/mingw/lib/libpthreadGC2.a
/mingw/lib/libpthreadGC2.dll.a
/mingw/lib/libpthreadGCE2.dll.a
/mingw/mingw32/include/pthread.h
/mingw/mingw32/lib/libpthread.a
/mingw/mingw32/lib/libpthread.dll.a
/mingw/mingw32/lib/libpthreadGC2.a
/mingw/mingw32/lib/libpthreadGC2.dll.a
/mingw/mingw32/lib/libpthreadGCE2.dll.a
/mingw/msys/1.0/include/pthread.h
/mingw/share/doc/pthreads-w32
/mingw/share/doc/pthreads-w32/2.9.1/README.pthreads-w32-2.9.1-1-mingw32
/mingw/var/cache/mingw-get/packages/pthreads-w32-2.9.1-1-mingw32-dev.tar.lzma
/mingw/var/cache/mingw-get/packages/pthreads-w32-2.9.1-1-mingw32-dll.tar.lzma
/mingw/var/cache/mingw-get/packages/pthreads-w32-2.9.1-1-mingw32-doc.tar.lzma
/mingw/var/cache/mingw-get/packages/pthreads-w32-2.9.1-1-mingw32-lic.tar.lzma
/mingw/var/lib/mingw-get/data/mingw32-pthreads-w32.xml
```

oh, god, where is the evil? `\` and `/` ?
helppppppppppp :|

Answer (score 0):

In case anyone is interested, check your config script. Thisissue comes when you mistake the *nix \ with windows /